# get value from javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

JS code:

```
 var createDistricts = {
     title: 'Add district',
     Url: params.urlCreateDistrict,
     data: {
         provinceId: provinceId
     },
     width: 600,
     buttons: [
     {
         text: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"</span Add',

             class: 'btn close',
             eventHandle: function () {
                 $(params.formAdd).submit();
             },
         },
         {
             text: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"</span Cancel',
             class: 'btn',
             eventHandle: function () {
                 $('#dialogHIA').modal('hide');
             },
         }
     ]
 };
 cm.ShowDialog(createDistricts);


}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CreateDistrict(HsmDistrict model, int? provinceId)
 {
     //model.ProvinceId = provinceId;

     model.CreatedBy = _userId;

     int checkFirst = _service.CheckComplic(model.DistrictId, "DistrictId", model.NativeName, "NativeName", "HsmDistrict");
     int checkSecond = _service.CheckComplic(model.DistrictId, "DistrictId", model.InternationalName, "InternationalName", "HsmDistrict");
     int checkThrid = _service.CheckComplic(model.DistrictId, "DistrictId", model.DistinctName, "DistinctName", "HsmDistrict");
     if (checkFirst == -1 || checkSecond == -1 || checkThrid == -1)
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "It's exist!");
         return PartialView("_CreateDistrict", model);
     }
     _service.CreateDistrict(model);
     return PartialView("_CreateDistrict", model);
 }
```

value provinceId from JS to Controller is null.

Comment: IMO this is hard to read and is not clear what your exact problem is. Please edit the question to format code.

Comment: is provinceId some sort of user input? It's not clear at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!